# Unextendable vector fields on $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $ M = \mathbb{S}^2 $ be a manifold with the coordinate patch $U$parameterized using spherical coordinates with $(\phi, \theta) \in (0,2\pi)\times (0,\pi)$. Let $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ be vector fields over $U$. Show $Y$ cannot be extended continously to a vector field in $\chi(M)$.

I am aware of the idea that I have to show that if I consider a patch that covers the points $ M -{U}$ then the vector field $Y$ won't be defined at least on the intersection of the patches. However, I am unsure how to achieve this. Moreover, is it correct to suggest that the information about the spherical coordinate parametrization is redundant since they have already provided me the $Y$ vector field?

Comment: What is $\chi(M)$ supposed to be?

Comment: The set of all vector fields in M

Comment: Look at the vector field $Y$ in cartesian coordinates. As you approach $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$, does it have a limiting value?

Comment: I believe no, because it doesnt depend on it.

Comment: I don't understand what you just said. What does the vector field $Y$ look like in a neighborhood of the north or south pole on the sphere?

Comment: I am intuitively aware that it has to approach infinity (due to the Hairy Ball theorem) but I am not sure if I can provide a mathematical argument to establish that.

Comment: All you need is for there to be no limit. The vectors can all stay bounded and still have no limit.